# Does http2 include a demux mechanism?

Tags: http2, multiplexing

As I simply understands HTTP2 is `m:1` pattern where you put `m` logical connections into `1` TCP stream

Is it possible to do `m:n` pattern in http2?

`m` streams are demuxed into `n` connections for better reliability, because often one single TCP breaks all h2 hangs.

Comment: "often one single TCP breaks" --- why does it?

Comment: @zerkms because in thirdworld countries ISP are very crappy. Connections are very congested and slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible, but in practice it is not done.

Browsers especially try hard to open just one connection to a domain, and even reuse the same connection for different subdomains if they can figure out that it resolves to the same IP address and same certificate.

Other clients may implement a `m:n` scheme (for example, [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) 9.4.x HTTP/2 client does - disclaimer: I'm the maintainer).

The problem of choosing a good `n` may not be trivial, and it risks to go back to HTTP/1.1 6-8 TCP connections per domain.

Since each connection would be multiplexed anyway, the failure of a single HTTP/2 connection would be worse than the failure of a single HTTP/1.1 connection (because it would fail multiple requests rather than just one), so I guess that it would not make that much of a difference with respect to a single HTTP/2 connection.

Google's [QUIC protocol](https://www.chromium.org/quic) aims at resolving this issue since it is based on UDP and has built-in in support for connection migration (i.e. switching from WiFi to mobile network).

Comment: Just out of my curiosity, could `m:n` H2 in theory saturate all bandwidth e.g. Multi NIC Ethernet+WIFI+LTE ? They must bind to multiple different interface I assume?